# When i try to define this vector< pair< int , pair<int, int> > > vp(n)

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, stdvector, push-back

There's in output Give me `0 0`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define fsv(i , n)  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int n ;
 cin >> n ;
 vector< pair< int , pair<int, int> > > vp(n);
 vector <int> v(n) ;

 fsv(i , v.size())cin >> v[i];

  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
     for(int j = i+1 ; j < n-1 ; ++j){
        vp.push_back(make_pair(abs(v[i]-v[j]) , make_pair(i,j)));
     }
  }
 sort(vp.begin() , vp.end());

 cout << vp[0].second.first << " " << vp[0].second.second;

}
```

this code related by code forces problem , i know that there's other ways ... but i'm asking this is proper way to access elements like that  ?!
http://codeforces.com/contest/34/problem/A

Comment: Please don't do this: `#define fsv(i , n)` - it really doesn't make your code easier to read or follow, on the contrary: now I have to think harder when reading it. Generally speaking in C++ avoid preprocessor macros wherever possible - and especially avoid them for control-flow statements.

Comment: Alternatively, `std::tuple<int, int, int>` as of C++11.

Comment: `vector< pair< int , pair<int, int> > > vp(n);` creates a vector that is filled with `n` default initialized elements. I wouldn't be surprised if one of those ends up being the first element after the `sort`

Comment: Also [don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/2069064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
vector< pair< int , pair<int, int> > > vp(n);
// ......................................^^^  n initial elements
```

initialize a vector with `n` elements and with `push_back()` you **add** **other** `n` elements`.

After sorting `v`, the `v[0]` element is (I suppose) one of the initials `n`.

You should create an **empty** vector

```
vector< pair< int , pair<int, int> > > vp;
// ....................................^^  no more initial elements; empy!
```

and, just to speed up and avoid a superfluous relocations, reserve `n` as size (but ins't necessary)

```
vp.reserve(n);
```

before pushing back `n` elements.

Off Topic suggestion: please, avoid including a not-standard header as

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Comment: I appreciated your help ... thanks a lot  , but we always in competitive programming contest find the fastest way and the least words (" i mean the code") to make it make fit in time and to get more rank

Comment: @AmirHaytham - It's the reason because I don't like competitive programming. I like good programs, not fast developed ones.